# How do I write a Keystone correction filter for VLC?

Tags: video, vlc, projector

How can I set up keystone correction in VLC? If this is not a supported feature, has anyone had any experience writing an add-on filter for VLC? If so, links/examples would be very appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Does your projector not have keystone correction?  Seems strange to do something like this in software when it's built into the hardware of pretty much every projector I've ever worked with.

Comment: just to clarify to those who wish to close this for SU. Keystone correction doesnt seem to be a current feature, so would need to be PROGRAMED

Comment: my projector has vertical keystone correction, but does not have horizontal correction, and I am forced to have my projector off to the side

Answer (score 2):

The reason I came looking for this feature is because the way projectors apply the correction is to start throwing away pixels (and hence light).  The way I would prefer to do it is by throwing away (ie masking/cropping) picture information.  In fact in my particular circumstance, I wouldn't actually be throwing away anything of value, since my image is not as wide as my projector's chip.  Provided the computational grunt was manageable, then I would vote for this as a worthwhile feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years but VLC still doesn't have keystoning feature. I have, however, found 2 software keystoning solutions in Microsoft Windows:

Movies:

- Use MPC-HC Player
- Install ffdshow tryouts (http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/)
- Enable ffdshow raw video filter
- Configure "perspective correction"

Entire desktop:

- Projection Mapper from NeuroRehabLab (http://download.cnet.com/Projection-Mapper/3000-20418_4-76027245.html)

This software is a tiny bit laggy, but still perfect for slideshows and other non-lag sensitive applications.